# Conditional probability distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

You are given that $N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean $4$. Define a new random variable
$M=(N - 4 \mid\ N \ge 4)$. Find the mean of $M$. Lost myself trying to solve this, help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: $E[N-4] = P(N=0) E[N-4|N=0] + \ldots + P(N=3) E[N-4|N=3] + P(N \ge 4) E[N-4|N \ge 4]$.